# Creating a query to retrieve certain rows in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have an orders table with a schema like this.

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id        int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    customer_id     int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    order_date      int NOT NULL
)
```

I'm trying to retrieve a list of each customers most recent order.  The table can have multiple orders by a customer, and each order has a primary key of order_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select o.*
from (
    select customer_id, max(order_date) as MaxOrderDate
    from orders
    group by customer_id
) om
inner join order o on om.customer_id = o.customer_id and om.MaxOrderDate = m.order_date
```

Answer (score 1):

As you use `AUTO_INCREMENT` for `order_id` the highest `order_id` per `customer_id` should be the latest:

```
Select customer_id, Max( order_id ) max_order_id
From orders
Group By customer_id
```

---

If you need all columns of that rows, you'd join a sub-select (**edited** to not depend on `order_id`):

```
Select o.customer_id, o.order_id, o.order_date
From orders o
Join (
    Select customer_id, Max( order_date ) max_order_date
    From orders
    Group By customer_id
) x On ( x.customer_id = c.customer_id AND x.max_order_date = o.order_date )
```

Comment: +1 for a simple and clean query without subqueries. this query should work for most recent orders as well by changing order_id to order_date

Comment: @Peter - because you are introducing two hidden dependencies - the first is that order_id is always increasing (what if it rolls over?) and the second is that the order_date cannot be changed (if it did, it would have no effect on the query).  On the plus side, both of those things are pretty unlikely, and the performance of that query would likely be better than any alternative.  Still scares me a bit though.

Comment: @PHP_Jedi: Thanks. I assumed that orders are inserted in the order of `order_date`, if this is not the case, then your suggestion is right.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize you can join on sub-selects like that.

Comment: @Eric Petroelje: Agreed, I edited the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE (customer_id, order_date) = 
        (select customer_id, max(order_date) from orders group by customer_id)`

Comment: This query uses a subquery... subqueries may be slow if the subqeury result is large.